# Set format of date to ui.boostrap.datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to set a format for the value of a datepicker, my datepicker:

```
<input id="date" name="date" type="text" uib-datepicker ng-model="vm.date">
```

I want `vm.date` to have a format of `dd-MM-yyyy`, currently the datepicker displays as:

[image: datepicker]

So is there any attribute to do that? Or do I necessary have to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21408016/3809894)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but the `uib-datepicker-popup` directive takes in the date format you want.  See [these docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) for more information.

As an aside, we've just added support for multiple date formats, i.e., the input is an array of acceptable formats rather than only one.  Note, however, that this feature is only available in `master` and is slated for the upcoming 1.0.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the on the template side rather than on the scope which makes things a bit easier.

```
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt|date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</em></pre>
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pSliYF?p=preview)

Comment: Would you please make an example of what I'm asking?

Comment: Sorry about that, using ui-date-format as in my original answer wasn't working at all. I edited rather than re-posting as I didn't want to leave that up in case it misled people.

Comment: Do I really need all those functions... I mean, I only need to save the date value in the binded model, what you've done is implement the answer I linked...

Comment: No you don't need any of them. They are just left in there from the original plunk. I've cleared them out now and updated the plunk.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want the value in the view, I need it in the ctrl, what I want to archive is to send the value already formatted to an endpoint...

Comment: I understand in that case the filter in code is the best way to go. `$filter('date')($scope.dt, 'dd-MM-yyyy')` . I've updated the plunk again with an example.